# iPod charging via USB cable

Tags: ipod-nano

I have a iPod Nano.

When I connect it to my PC (Windows 7) with the USB cable, iTunes is started. I guess the iPod battery starts charging. If I say "Eject" the iPod from the Windows Explorer or "Disconnect" it from iTunes, but still keep the cable connected, will it continue charging?

Or for charging to continue, does iPod  needs to be connected to iTunes or recognized in the Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will charge even if you "Eject" it from Windows Explorer or "Disconnect" from iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will continue charging as you hope. All that is required for it to charge is to be connected (via its USB cable) to a power source of the appropriate power configuration.

In fact, you don’t even need to connect it to the computer to charge, you can connect to a powered USB hub instead (eg a four-port USB hub that has a power-adapter), or charge it by connecting it to a power adapter with a USB port built-in (these usually come with other chargeable USB devices like portable GPS systems).

Finally, you can even build your own charger since it is so basic.

In summary, no, it does not have to be mounted on the computer in order to charge.